# Buildozer Android APK OSError debug

Tags: python, android, kivy, torch, buildozer

I have been trying to make a APK off of a program i wrote in python on my windows machine. Its been couple days when i first tried using buildozer and i have come a long way from bug fixing into switching to a VM and doing all over again. So now i am kinda stuck since two days. Im getting a pretty straight forward error which i should be able to fix easily. I have screenshotted the important part of the error to show it to you guys. I possibly tried everything you could have done. I used different torch Versions, i tried different Android devices, played alot with the buildozer.spec and so on. I simply cannot fix this bug. Maybe there is a Soul out here that knows how to fix my issue.

here is my buildozer.spec file with some stuff deleted on stackoverflow to not be marked as spam. The things that arent presented here werent changed.

EDIT:

I have been talking to one of the guys from Kivy, and i have been told that i need to write a recipe to translate torch from one Operation System to another. So there starts a new problem.. has anyone ever worked on that kind of stuff and give me some tips?

```
# (list) Application requirements
# comma separated e.g. requirements = sqlite3,kivy
requirements = python3,appdirs==1.4.4,asgiref,autoconf,certifi,charset-normalizer,cmake,colorama,cycler,Django,docutils,idna,image,importlib-metadata,Jinja2,Kivy==2.0.0,Kivy-Garden,kivymd,kiwisolver,MarkupSafe,matplotlib,mypy-extensions,numpy,nums-from-string,pep517,pillow==8.4.0,Pygments,pyparsing,python-dateutil,python-for-android,pytoml,pytz,PyYAML,requests,sh,six,sqlparse,toml,torch==1.10.0,torchvision==0.11.1,typing-extensions,typing-inspect


# change the major version of python used by the app
osx.python_version = 3

# Kivy version to use
osx.kivy_version = 2.0.0

#
# Android specific
#

# (list) Permissions
#android.permissions = INTERNET

# (list) features (adds uses-feature -tags to manifest)
#android.features = android.hardware.usb.host

# (int) Target Android API, should be as high as possible.
#android.api = 27

# (int) Minimum API your APK will support.
#android.minapi = 21

# (int) Android SDK version to use
#android.sdk = 20

# (str) Android NDK version to use
#android.ndk = 19b

# (int) Android NDK API to use. This is the minimum API your app will support, it should usually match android.minapi.
#android.ndk_api = 21

# (str) Android logcat filters to use
android.logcat_filters = *:S python:D

# (bool) Android logcat only display log for activity's pid
#android.logcat_pid_only = False

# (str) Android additional adb arguments
#android.adb_args = -H host.docker.internal

# (bool) Copy library instead of making a libpymodules.so
#android.copy_libs = 1

# (str) The Android arch to build for, choices: armeabi-v7a, arm64-v8a, x86, x86_64
android.arch = arm64-v8a

# (int) overrides automatic versionCode computation (used in build.gradle)
# this is not the same as app version and should only be edited if you know what you're doing
# android.numeric_version = 1

#    -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

and here is my error that i get
[adb debug error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iu9e1.png)

---

EDIT:

Heres the new debug messages

```
--------- beginning of crash
--------- beginning of main
--------- beginning of system
12-08 03:16:04.918 18201 21296 I python  : Initializing Python for Android
12-08 03:16:04.918 18201 21296 I python  : Setting additional env vars from p4a_env_vars.txt
12-08 03:16:04.918 18201 21296 I python  : Changing directory to the one provided by ANDROID_ARGUMENT
12-08 03:16:04.918 18201 21296 I python  : /data/user/0/org.test.fedlearn/files/app
12-08 03:16:04.921 18201 21296 I python  : Preparing to initialize python
12-08 03:16:04.921 18201 21296 I python  : _python_bundle dir exists
12-08 03:16:04.921 18201 21296 I python  : calculated paths to be...
12-08 03:16:04.921 18201 21296 I python  : /data/user/0/org.test.fedlearn/files/app/_python_bundle/stdlib.zip:/data/user/0/org.test.fedlearn/files/app/_python_bundle/modules
12-08 03:16:04.948 18201 21296 I python  : set wchar paths...
12-08 03:16:05.030 18201 21296 I python  : Initialized python
12-08 03:16:05.030 18201 21296 I python  : AND: Init threads
12-08 03:16:05.031 18201 21296 I python  : testing python print redirection
12-08 03:16:05.032 18201 21296 I python  : Android path ['.', '/data/user/0/org.test.fedlearn/files/app/_python_bundle/stdlib.zip', '/data/user/0/org.test.fedlearn/files/app/_python_bundle/modules', '/data/user/0/org.test.fedlearn/files/app/_python_bundle/site-packages']
12-08 03:16:05.032 18201 21296 I python  : os.environ is environ({'PATH': '/product/bin:/apex/com.android.runtime/bin:/apex/com.android.art/bin:/system_ext/bin:/system/bin:/system/xbin:/odm/bin:/vendor/bin:/vendor/xbin', 'ANDROID_BOOTLOGO': '1', 'ANDROID_ROOT': '/system', 'ANDROID_ASSETS': '/system/app', 'ANDROID_DATA': '/data', 'ANDROID_STORAGE': '/storage', 'ANDROID_ART_ROOT': '/apex/com.android.art', 'ANDROID_I18N_ROOT': '/apex/com.android.i18n', 'ANDROID_TZDATA_ROOT': '/apex/com.android.tzdata', 'EXTERNAL_STORAGE': '/sdcard', 'ASEC_MOUNTPOINT': '/mnt/asec', 'BOOTCLASSPATH': '/apex/com.android.art/javalib/core-oj.jar:/apex/com.android.art/javalib/core-libart.jar:/apex/com.android.art/javalib/core-icu4j.jar:/apex/com.android.art/javalib/okhttp.jar:/apex/com.android.art/javalib/bouncycastle.jar:/apex/com.android.art/javalib/apache-xml.jar:/system/framework/framework.jar:/system/framework/ext.jar:/system/framework/telephony-common.jar:/system/framework/smartbondingservice.jar:/system/framework/voip-common.jar:/system/framework/ims-common.jar:/system/framework/knoxanalyticssdk.jar:/system/framework/fipstimakeystore.jar:/system/framework/timakeystore.jar:/system/framework/knoxsdk.jar:/system/framework/drutils.jar:/system/framework/framework-atb-backward-compatibility.jar:/system/framework/SmpsManager.jar:/system/framework/esecomm.jar:/system/framework/uibc_java.jar:/system/framework/ICDVerification.jar:/system/framework/tcmiface.jar:/system/framework/telephony-ext.jar:/system/framework/QPerformance.jar:/system/framework/UxPerformance.jar:/apex/com.android.conscrypt/javalib/conscrypt.jar:/apex/com.android.media/javalib/updatable-media.jar:/apex/com.android.mediaprovider/javalib/framework-mediaprovider.jar:/apex/com.android.os.statsd/javalib/framework-statsd.jar:/apex/com.android.permission/javalib/framework-permission.jar:/apex/com.android.sdkext/javalib/framework-sdkextensions.jar:/apex/com.android.wifi/javalib/framework-wifi.jar:/apex/com.android.tethering/javalib/framework-tethering.jar:/apex/com.samsung.android.shell/javalib/framework-samsung-privilege.jar', 'DEX2OATBOOTCLASSPATH': '/apex/com.android.art/javalib/core-oj.jar:/apex/com.android.art/javalib/core-libart.jar:/apex/com.android.art/javalib/core-icu4j.jar:/apex/com.android.art/javalib/okhttp.jar:/apex/com.android.art/javalib/bouncycastle.jar:/apex/com.android.art/javalib/apache-xml.jar:/system/framework/framework.jar:/system/framework/ext.jar:/system/framework/telephony-common.jar:/system/framework/smartbondingservice.jar:/system/framework/voip-common.jar:/system/framework/ims-common.jar:/system/framework/knoxanalyticssdk.jar:/system/framework/fipstimakeystore.jar:/system/framework/timakeystore.jar:/system/framework/knoxsdk.jar:/system/framework/drutils.jar:/system/framework/framework-atb-backward-compatibility.jar:/system/framework/SmpsManager.jar:/system/framework/esecomm.jar:/system/framework/uibc_java.jar:/system/framework/ICDVerification.jar:/system/framework/tcmiface.jar:/system/framework/telephony-ext.jar:/system/framework/QPerformance.jar:/system/framework/UxPerformance.jar', 'SYSTEMSERVERCLASSPATH': '/system/framework/com.android.location.provider.jar:/system/framework/services.jar:/system/framework/ethernet-service.jar:/system/framework/ssrm.jar:/system/framework/semwifi-service.jar:/apex/com.android.permission/javalib/service-permission.jar:/apex/com.android.wifi/javalib/service-wifi.jar:/apex/com.android.ipsec/javalib/android.net.ipsec.ike.jar:/apex/com.samsung.android.shell/javalib/service-samsung-privilege.jar', 'DOWNLOAD_CACHE': '/data/cache', 'KNOX_STORAGE': '/data/knox/ext_sdcard', 'ENC_EMULATED_STORAGE_TARGET': '/storage/enc_emulated', 'ANDROID_SOCKET_zygote': '18', 'ANDROID_SOCKET_usap_pool_primary': '23', 'ANDROID_ENTRYPOINT': 'main.pyc', 'ANDROID_ARGUMENT': '/data/user/0/org.test.fedlearn/files/app', 'ANDROID_APP_PATH': '/data/user/0/org.test.fedlearn/files/app', 'ANDROID_PRIVATE': '/data/user/0/org.test.fedlearn/files', 'ANDROID_UNPACK': '/data/user/0/org.test.fedlearn/files/app', 'PYTHONHOME': '/data/user/0/org.test.fedlearn/files/app', 'PYTHONP
12-08 03:16:05.032 18201 21296 I python  : Android kivy bootstrap done. __name__ is __main__
12-08 03:16:05.032 18201 21296 I python  : AND: Ran string
12-08 03:16:05.032 18201 21296 I python  : Run user program, change dir and execute entrypoint
12-08 03:16:05.224 18201 21296 I python  : [WARNING] [Config      ] Older configuration version detected (0 instead of 21)
12-08 03:16:05.225 18201 21296 I python  : [WARNING] [Config      ] Upgrading configuration in progress.
12-08 03:16:05.240 18201 21296 I python  : [INFO   ] [Logger      ] Record log in /data/user/0/org.test.fedlearn/files/app/.kivy/logs/kivy_21-12-08_0.txt
12-08 03:16:05.241 18201 21296 I python  : [INFO   ] [Kivy        ] v2.0.0
12-08 03:16:05.241 18201 21296 I python  : [INFO   ] [Kivy        ] Installed at "/data/user/0/org.test.fedlearn/files/app/_python_bundle/site-packages/kivy/__init__.pyc"
12-08 03:16:05.241 18201 21296 I python  : [INFO   ] [Python      ] v3.8.9 (default, Dec  8 2021, 02:29:44) 
12-08 03:16:05.241 18201 21296 I python  : [Clang 8.0.2 (https://android.googlesource.com/toolchain/clang 40173bab62ec7462
12-08 03:16:05.241 18201 21296 I python  : [INFO   ] [Python      ] Interpreter at ""
12-08 03:16:06.556 18201 21296 I python  : [INFO   ] [Factory     ] 186 symbols loaded
12-08 03:16:07.037 18201 21296 I python  : [INFO   ] [Image       ] Providers: img_tex, img_dds, img_sdl2, img_pil (img_ffpyplayer ignored)
12-08 03:16:07.545 18201 21296 I python  :  Traceback (most recent call last):
12-08 03:16:07.546 18201 21296 I python  :    File "/home/karen/Desktop/FederatedLearning/python/client/code/.buildozer/android/app/main.py", line 8, in <module>
12-08 03:16:07.546 18201 21296 I python  :    File "/home/karen/Desktop/FederatedLearning/python/client/code/.buildozer/android/app/observer.py", line 1, in <module>
12-08 03:16:07.546 18201 21296 I python  :    File "/home/karen/Desktop/FederatedLearning/python/client/code/.buildozer/android/app/api/model_listener.py", line 2, in <module>
12-08 03:16:07.547 18201 21296 I python  :    File "/home/karen/Desktop/FederatedLearning/python/client/code/.buildozer/android/app/lib/datamanager.py", line 1, in <module>
12-08 03:16:07.547 18201 21296 I python  :    File "/home/karen/Desktop/FederatedLearning/python/client/code/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a/build/python-installs/Fedlearn/torch/__init__.py", line 196, in <module>
12-08 03:16:07.547 18201 21296 I python  :    File "/home/karen/Desktop/FederatedLearning/python/client/code/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a/build/python-installs/Fedlearn/torch/__init__.py", line 149, in _load_global_deps
12-08 03:16:07.547 18201 21296 I python  :    File "/home/karen/Desktop/FederatedLearning/python/client/code/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a/build/other_builds/python3/arm64-v8a__ndk_target_21/python3/Lib/ctypes/__init__.py", line 373, in __init__
12-08 03:16:07.548 18201 21296 I python  :  OSError: dlopen failed: "/data/user/0/org.test.fedlearn/files/app/_python_bundle/site-packages/torch/lib/libtorch_global_deps.so" is for EM_X86_64 (62) instead of EM_AARCH64 (183)
12-08 03:16:07.548 18201 21296 I python  : Python for android ended.
```

Comment: I also have been playing with the android.arch's and the torch versions synchronously.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.